# How to create a kubernetes service for a container without a port

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose, kubernetes-service

I am bringing an application which consists of different components to Kubernetes. Now I faced with some components that their compose file doesn't have any port and I don't know how to create a service for them. I checked those components and their network settings are as below:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "Ports": {},
    "Gateway": "172.18.133.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "172.18.133.14",
    [other-configs]
}
```

How can we create services for these kind of components?

Comment: did you default port 80

Comment: I can say this is my question (in other words) what is the default port if we don't define a port in compose file or when we use `docker run`? And to answer your question no I didn't define a default port and the compose file that I use for `docker-compose` doesn't have a port field at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a big difference between plain Docker/Docker Compose and Kubernetes.  In Docker, one container can reach another using the other container's name as a hostname and any port the container happens to be listening on, without any special declarations.  In Kubernetes all pod-to-pod communication generally goes via a service.

Even if you're not publishing a container's ports externally, its Dockerfile will often contain an `EXPOSE` declaration naming some specific ports, and you can put these in the pod and service spec.  If you don't have the Dockerfile `docker history` or `docker inspect` could tell you.  Absent even that information, you'll have to use other possibly non-technical means to find it out.

If a container doesn't accept inbound connections at all (it's a worker container for a job-queueing system, for example) you may not need a Service at all.

If you don't accept inbound connections, but still need a Service (this is [a requirement when using Istio](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/prepare/requirements/)) then the Service needs to declare

```
type: ClusterIP
clusterIP: None
```

This isn't documented well, but there does turn out to be a rule in code that a Service must have at least one port without this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about public access, according to the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports),

> By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of
>   its ports to the outside world. To make a port available to services
>   outside of Docker, or to Docker containers which are not connected to
>   the container’s network, use the --publish or -p flag.

If you are referring to inter-container communication on docker-compose, you will have to check your application as ports do not require "exposing" on the docker network.

Comment: I am talking about docker-compose and I want to know how can I create a service for such a container in Kubernetes. All my other containers have exposing ports in their compose files and I used those ports for my service definition but there are two that don't have ports and I found out that other components are communicating with these two via AMQP but as I said there is no explicit port exposed. At the moment I am looking to see how stuff is working under the hood for those components.